# Ошибка/предупреждение при запуске: "bash: ConEmu: command not found"

Tags: bash

В какой-то момент Bash при старте стал выдавать такое предупреждение:

```
bash: ConEmu: command not found
```

Предупреждение появляется после каждой команды.
Переустановка не помогает.

Связано ли это с переменной PATH?

Comment: Смотрите в сохранённых файлах в домашнем каталоге пользователя. Скорее всего какая-то установка включилась, которую вы не знаете как выключить. Переустановка, естественно, не поможет.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду посмотреть файлы в этой директории? 
C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\Temp\ConEmu

Comment: `bash -l -x` и узнаете из какого файла запускается эта ваша программа `ConEmu`

Comment: Спасибо, причина была в файле .bashrc, который лежит в профиле пользователя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

выполнение этой программы (`ConEmu`) упомянуто в каком-то из скриптов, которые интерпретирует программа *bash* при запуске.

чтобы определить имя файла с этим скриптом, можно запустить программу *bash* с опцией `-x` (трассировка):

```
$ bash -x
```

---

предупреждение: вывод может быть очень длинный. сохранить его в файл (чтобы удобнее было просматривать) можно, например, с помощью программы *script*, вызвав её так:

```
$ script -c 'bash -x'
```

запущенный экземпляр программы *bash* можно сразу же завершить либо командой `exit`, либо нажав сочетание клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, программа *script* при этом тоже завершится и напишет напоминание:

```
Script done, file is typescript
```

вот в этом файле — `typescript` — в текущем каталоге и сохранён весь длинный вывод команды `bash -x`.

---

в выводе команды `bash -x` надо надо найти упоминание интересующей нас программы (`ConEmu`). он будет выглядеть, скорее всего, примерно так:

```
++ ConEmu какие-нибудь аргументы
```

в начале строки стоят символы `+`. их количество показывает уровень вложенности.

надо подняться выше по выводу до первой строки, которая начинается с количества символов `+`, на единицу меньшего, чем в найденной строке с упоминанием интересующей нас программы (`ConEmu`). т.е., для данного случая что-нибдуь вроде:

```
+ . /путь/к/скрипту
```

вот это и будет искомый файл со скриптом, в котором упомянута интересующая нас программа (`ConEmu`).

что дальше делать с этим упоминанием, надеюсь, понятно.

---

ах, да:

> Связано ли это с переменной PATH?

вряд ли.

Comment: `что дальше делать с этим упоминанием, надеюсь, понятно.` Не понятно

Comment: его надо удалить.