# Сообщение при запуске в консоли Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Каждый раз при старте новой консоли первой строкой выводится:

> ```
> bash: export: `WORKON_HOME/projects=~/Env': неправильный идентификатор
> ```

Появилось после установки virtualenv. На данный момент virtualennv удалил, сообщение осталось. Что сделать что бы удалить эту строчку?

Comment: Покажи ~/.bashrc

Comment: смотри в каком из файлов запускаемых оболочкой при старте эта строчка затисалась и удали её. Основной подозреваемый — `~/.bashrc`. Можно также `grep`'нуть `~/.??*` и `/etc` на предмет её наличия...

Comment: Да, нашел строки в ~/.bashrc. Спасибо

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835688/178576